# Xcode universal app iPad UITableView size

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, ios-universal-app

I've created an universal app in Xcode 6 and the iPhone storyboard has a UIViewController that contains a UITableView, it works fine. I made the iPad storyboard the same as the iPhone and added all the classes and elements but the UITableView is displayed very small. On my storyboard the UITableView is fullscreen but when I run the iPad app it is displayed like the image below.

I read something about the UISplitViewController but I don't want to split the view. Why is this displayed smaller than I've created on my storyboard?

**ANSWER**

The wrong `Storyboard` was targeted in the `segue` so it got linked to my iPhone storyboard, that's why the `tableView` was the size of an iPhone. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not using Auto Layout and forgot to set Autoresizing.

Comment: Auto Layout is turned on, where can I enable Autoresizing? I'm using Xcode 6 by the way.

Comment: If you are using Auto Layout, follow advices of Signo. Be sure to check storyboard for iPhone too. In the case of different width of device, problem may occur unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Add Constraint to the TableView in order to auto-resize it based on the screen size

Comment: How can I do that? I selected the UITableView and Add Missing Constraints and I can also set the Width and Height but how can I base that on the screen size?

Comment: select your UITableView then click here http://captechconsulting.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/20130911_5_0.png?itok=m01AZ4YM 
and select "Reset to suggested constraints"

Comment: It will automatically attach your uitableView to the View so if the screen gets larger the uitableView will adapt to it

Comment: I just found out it is not just the UITableView that shrinks, the background gradient is an ImageView and is also smaller than it should be. So I guess my general View is the one that shrinks and the UITableView and ImageView are adjusting to the View. How can I add constraints to the View of a ViewController?

Comment: in order to add constraints to every element you'll just need to open the menu i've shown you before and click "Reset to suggested constraints in View", xcode will automatically add every needed constraint

Comment: If I select the View and click "Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Reset to suggested Constraints" nothing happens.

Comment: First click "Clear Constraints" in order to delete the constraints you've added before then add them again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62321/discussion-between-speetje33-and-signo).